# How to encode a video with subtitles to a hls streaming with subtitles on azure media services

Tags: http-live-streaming, azure-media-services, webvtt

Having a mp4 video and its vtt subtitle file, how can I encode this video to a h264 multiple bitrate adaptative streaming including subtitles?
How I have to include caption files in the encoding process?

Answer (score 1):

We only have a solution that is specific to Azure Media Player. Go to http://aka.ms/azuremediaplayer, and in the Samples drop down, select “Subtitles (WebVTT) – On Demand[Tears of Steel]”. This will show you an example where the multiple bitrate MP4 files are stored in one Asset and published, and the WebVTT is stored in a separate asset with its own locator.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Who do you you mean by "We" in the first sentence?